# Is this the correct way to dynamically allocate a float variable

Tags: c++

In this code, is this the correct way?

```
float pf = (float) malloc (sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Show some context.

Comment: Why would you ever dynamically allocate a float object?

Comment: Since that line does not compile, I would have to say it is blatantly not correct. Perhaps you could come up with something that does compile? Explain why dynamic allocation is needed in your situation?

Comment: Although it's absolutely a bad practice, but I can tell you `float* pf = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));` shall compile.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way.  It is incorrect on several different levels of severity.

First, a dynamically allocation of an object of any type returns a pointer to an object, not the object itself.

A dynamically allocated float will return a pointer to a float,  so the declaration would be `float *pf = (float*) ...`

Which means that the cast would be `(float*) not (float)`.

Going deeper, since the language tag is C++ using malloc is incorrect, or at best outdated.  Use new and delete, not malloc and free.

Instead of C-style casting (float*), static_cast would be the modern C++ choice.

The code could easily be fixed to be correct, in the sense of compiling and giving the correct result.  Then there's another big step from "it works" to "best practices."

Comment: Going deeper, don't use `new` and `delete`, since C++11 you should be using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique()`, or `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared()`.